# Dataframe to dict, Excel

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel

I want the excel information to go back to the dictionary when I restart the program or add new information. When I add new information in this format the program rewrites the excel.

```
import pandas as pd

teacher_data = {'Registration': [], 'Name': [], 'Birth_Date': []}

while True:
    Option = int(input("1 - Register Teachers\n"
                      "\nChoose one of the alternatives: "))
    if Option == 1:  # Cadastro dos professores
        Registration_number = input("\nRegistration Number: ")
        Name_Teacher = input("Name of teacher: ")
        date_teacher = input("Birth_date: ")
        print('Registered Teacher')

        teacher_data['Registration'] += [Registration_number]
        teacher_data['Name'] += [Name_Teacher]
        teacher_data['Birth_Date'] += [date_teacher]
        print(teacher_data)
        excel = pd.DataFrame(data=teacher_data)
        with pd.ExcelWriter('Registered_Teachers.xlsx') as writer:
            excel.to_excel(writer, index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use openpyxl lib for your purpose.

PyPi --> [Click Here](https://pypi.org/project/openpyxl/)

Docs --> [Click Here](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)